# Listbox resizing itself when new data is added

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add information to my Listbox and keeping it the size I state when I configure it. Here is my code for the Listbox with the scrollbar and an image of what it looks like.

*Picture of the listbox.*
[image: picture of the listbox]

```
taskList = Listbox(setBox, bg="#1B2834",fg="white")
taskList.configure(width=183,height=39)
taskList.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)

taskScroll = Scrollbar(setBox)
taskScroll.configure(bg="#1B2834",width=18)
taskScroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH)

taskList.config(yscrollcommand = taskScroll.set) 
taskScroll.config(command = taskList.yview)
```

Now, when i click a button the command is to execute this following code:

```
def savetasks():
    #make tasks
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(4))
    num = str(random.randrange(0,9))
    taskIDnum = num+result_str
    
    taskIDLBL = Label(taskList, text=taskIDnum,bg="#1B2834", fg="White")
    taskIDLBL.configure(padx=20,pady=10)
    taskIDLBL.pack()
```

This code works fine as well, creating new labels with a random ID but it resizes the listbox to look like this...

*Picture of the list box after clicking the button to execute the command.*
[image: picture of list box after clicking the button to execute the command.]

Lastly, the scroll bar is not scrollable and when I create a lot of id's that end up going off my screen I cannot use the scroll bar to scroll down to see them, is there a way to not let the Listbox be resized and is it possible to set the Listbox with max and min-height?

*If there is an easier way to do this without using a Listbox please let know, I just need to able to scroll down to see all the other id's and I didn't see any other way to use a scroll bar, that I NEEDED to use a Listbox*

Comment: Why don't you just call `taskList.insert('end', taskIDnum)` instead of creating label?  Using `pack()` to insert labels into listbox will expand the listbox.

Comment: You should not be adding Label widgets to a listbox. That is not how a listbox is designed to work. The labels won't be scrollable or selectable.

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you this is a much smarter option. Is there a way i can make spaces between each, i dont like how they are so tightly packed together. i would like to be able to make spaces between each and be able to move them around in the list box. In the future i plan on adding more text next to each id so to be able to space them out from one another would be ideal,. basically like how padx and pady work.

Comment: @acw1668 i also noticed that a line appears under the elements i am adding, is there a way to remove this? i tried setting active state to none but it didnt work.

Comment: Line spacing is not support in `Listbox`, you can use `Text` which does support.  For the underline, use `activestype='none'`.